# Member variable of type std::array<T, ?>

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

How do I declare and set a member variable for a template class AClass which is of type `std::array<T, ?>` (with undefined size)? The actual `std::array` is to be created in the constructor, where the size of the array is a constructor parameter.

In pseudo-C++ code:

```
template <typename T> class AClass {

protected:
    std::array<T, ?>* array;

public:

    AClass(int n) {
        this->array = new std::array<T, n>;
    }

}
```

How would correct code look like?

Comment: What is the `new` for?

Comment: This is completely not what `std::array` is for, and you cannot pass a parameter to a template like that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Tell me why it is wrong here (ignoring the fact that this is impossible since the size of an `std::array` must be a compile-time constant).

Comment: @cls: #1 it does not compile because the member is not a pointer; #2 it leaks resources because it gives up on compiler-guaranteed destructor calls.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes #1 is clear, I've changed that in the question. #2: How to create a new member object in the constructor correctly?

Comment: `AClass(int n) : array() {}` would work fine (ignoring the fact the size must ne available at compile time), or `AClass(int n) : array(n) {}` for a vector member. In general you can use `T()` to create an object of type `T`; no `new` involved, this is not Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use `std::array` for that, use `std::vector`. The size of an `std::array` must be a compile-time constant. If you want to pass it in the constructor, you need to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Or `std::unique_ptr<T[]> array` if resizing and other `vector` features are not required.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if this has any benefit at all. The syntax is certainly more complicated, and I doubt that it is significantly faster or more memory-efficient.

Comment: I don't think it'll be any faster, but it does have slightly less memory overhead than a `vector`. As I said, if resizing is not required, it may be worth considering, otherwise use `vector`.

Comment: @Praetorian what slightly less overhead? If anything, `unique_ptr<T[]>` has underhead, because it knows not its size.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Isn't that what I said also? That `unique_ptr<T[]>` has less memory overhead compared to `vector`?

Answer (score 9):

> The actual `std::array` is to be created in the constructor, where **the size of the array is a constructor parameter.**

The size of a `std::array` must be known at compile time, which in your case it isn't.

You'll have to use `std::vector` for this.

Answer (score 5):

Separate from using `std::vector` where the size is truly defined at runtime, you could also choose to specify the size at compile time (e.g. to the maximum possible value depending on your problem) and 'propagate' the template parameter to clients of your class i.e.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n> 
class AClass {
   protected:
       std::array<T, n> array;
   public:
       AClass() {
           // nothing to do
       }
}
```

you then use it like this:

```
AClass<int, 5> myAClass;
```

Comment: Yes, but there's an explicit requirement for the size of the array to be a constructor parameter. Here, it isn't and can't be.

Comment: depends on the true requirement of the OP, some times OP introduce unnecessary requirements and indeed the size is known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `std::array` with undefined size.
Use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or `std::vector` instead.